# Need help in lift system using java

Tags: java

I have a code which serves only one request a time .can anyone help pls

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


          ElevatorImpl elevator = ElevatorImpl.getInstance();
          elevator.setCurrentFloor(0); // assumption that lift is in ground floor initially


          ElevatorManager elevatorManager = new ElevatorManager(elevator);
          elevatorManager.addPickUp(new RequestDTO(1,10,30)); // first user access the lift at ground floor and want to go to 10th floor
          elevatorManager.addPickUp(new RequestDTO(5,0,50));
          elevatorManager.addPickUp(new RequestDTO(2,4,400));
          elevatorManager.addPickUp(new RequestDTO(4,3,60));
          elevatorManager.execute();

}
```

Comment: Can you please say a bit more about what the code does now, what it is supposed to do, and what gap between these two you want help bridging?

Comment: Sure Jeremy.. currently my program does serving one request at a time ... Like for eg ..if person one enters at source 2 and wants to go to destination 10 ,it can go but for second person, say if person enters at source 3 , it doesn't stop there and drops to destination 10 and then only serve next request

Comment: Kindly let me know to make the code efficient by serving user requests near by

Comment: so could you queue up all of them and say, for now I'm going up. Anybody to drop off here? If so, stop to let them off. Anybody wanting to get on and want to head up? Great, stop and let them on (if there is room). Now assuming someone is on who wants to keep moving up or (perhaps) someone above where we are wants to get on, then keep moving up. If not, see if there is anyone below us needing service. When you let people on, make sure it is clear they are no longer waiting. There are definitely possible efficiency improvements, biut get something working like that, I think, then adjust.

Comment: I have no idea on how can I implement...can u help pls..

Comment: please edit the question itself ... if any one wants to help they would have to go through the comments.. which is not convenient .

Comment: Sure Tushar ..will do

Answer (score 1):

Lets say we have an elevator class, we can store current floor and direction of elevator.

```
class Elevator{
    int currentFloor;
    Direction direction;

    enum Direction{
         UP,DOWN;
    }
}
```

now we as the elevator starts to move at each floor it can check two things.

1.if someone wants to get down at this floor

2.is someone waiting at this floor and wants to move in the same direction as lift

so at each floor if above condition gets satisfied lift stops.
if some one boards in we add that to list of elevator stops
if some one leaves we remove that stop from the list

so we can maintain a list in elevator manager class which stores user requests

```
List<RequestDTO> requestList = new ArrayList<>();
```

and another list which maintains floor where elevator is supposed to stop

```
List<Integers> stops = new ArrayList<>();
```

now we can subsequently perform operation for current floor

once lift reaches terminal floor(either top or ground) reverse the direction of lift

```
while(true){
    if(isDeboarding(currentFloor)){
       //remove current floor from boarded user
    }
    if(pendingRequestInSameDirection(currentFloor)){
       //remove current floor from request list
       //add requested floor in stops list
    }
    if(elevator.Direction == Direction.UP){
       currentFloor++;
    }else{
       currentFloor--;
    }
}
```